# Locked out from SSH, NetBoot can be useful?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, netboot

I am operating on a Server that is on a datacenter.
For security reasons I've disabled root access.
So yesterday I was configuring a restricted access group on the server and accidentally put the only sudoer and ssh enabled user under the group and now I'm locked off my machine.  There are months of work and configuration and effort and time on this machine running Ubuntu server 14.04.

On my dashboard of the datacenter there is an option called NetBoot.
If I open this there are 3 options: "HardDisk, Network, Rescue". I don't know what it is but i'm guessing if I can get in in some way and edit the ~/.ssh/config.

Comment: Contact your DC provider for remote-hands.

Comment: You can restore from your backups, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rescue option will probably drop you into a root shell, or possibly a live CD environment such as Knoppix.  From there you can edit any configuration files you need.